# how can I design a class with one variable and still work with different variables at the same time?

Tags: c++, class, design-patterns, class-hierarchy

I have a code design question.

I have built a class that is meant to analyze a sample of data. It considers a sample and analyzes the sample. For example, it can compute the sample mean and sample variance. Therefore, in its most rudimentary form it looks like this in the header file:

```
class Statistic{
public:
    // constructors
    Statistic();
    Statistic(vector<double> &s);

    // other functions
    double calcMean(void);
    double calcMean(vector<double> &s);
    double calcVariance(void);

private:
    vector<double> sample;
};
```

Now I would like to write a function `calcCovariance` that can compute the covariance between two samples. Its definition would be something like this:

```
double calcCovariance(vector<double> &s1, vector<double> &s2);
```

However, the class only contains one private variable called `sample`. How can I best design my class hierarchy such that my class only contains one variable `sample`, and I can still work with several samples at the same time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you mean that you want your private `vector` variable to be accessible from other objects of the same class, you can make it protected instead of private.

Comment: You could expose the `sample` variable you already have.

Comment: The best design would be to not use classes at all.

Comment: @STLDeveloper: what do you mean with "expose"?

Comment: @juanchopanza: why would that be best?

Comment: Well, what do you gain from using classes here? Is there a single good reason to use one?

Comment: @Linuxios: but in that case I would be forced to call a class method that has two input variables: one vector from the object itself and one from another object. Seems fuzzy ….

Comment: @juanchopanza: I don't know for sure, I am a beginner. However, if I want to enlarge my code in the future (likely so), I better define a class with a clear structure….. no?

Comment: How about a vector of vectors? `std::vector<std::vector<double>> samples;`

Comment: Simply using classes doesn't make code better or easier to understand. Looking at your code, it looks like you are better off with some non-member functions acting on one or more vectors.

Comment: @LarsSorjetasek no, your code doesn't get magically better if you will wrap it with class. Quite frankly you can have large, and manageable, code bases without using class once. And you can also have the opposite - code with plethora of classes which is unmaintainable. You have to use common sense and harness the power of class when you need it, where you will benefit from some of it's properties.

Comment: @LarsSorjetasek: Since you're passing both sample sets as parameters to the function, why is a member variable required?

Comment: They do make a good point that you don't necessarily gain anything by using classes here. These functions could be standalone.

Comment: @outis: you think just declaring the variable(s) in the main would be better?

Comment: @splrs: I understand that defining a class does not always help. However, I intend to use this class in many instances and thought it would be good to make it a class for that reason ….

Comment: Well if you want a class then write a class. But it really doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Yes but none of those functions seem to add anything by being specifically part of that class, and once you get rid of those and make them static, you've just got the vector. So why not just pass the vectors around? The point is, if you're storing a vector of these objects, you could just be storing a vector of vectors instead.

Comment: @Puciek: see my reply above….

Comment: @splrs: but when would a function then add anything to a class? Seems a rather strange question, I know, but one can always code anything in a functional way if it is coded in a OO way...

Comment: @LarsSorjetasek this is really derailing a lot, and most likely is too deep to be covered in simple SO question. We don't know your full scope, just small piece of it. If you have exact questions - you will get answers but we won't design your whole application for you, only help with small uncertain bits.

Comment: @LarsSorjetasek Often for much more hidden state than in this instance. Your only functions are all public and they do a simple thing, there's no real compelling reason to make them specific to the class, for example, would `double calcMean(vector<double> &s)` ever do anything different from the obvious? Would it need to be overidden to act in a different way?

Comment: @splrs thanks for your answer. However, would one reason not be to avoid writing the same function over and over again (be it a trivial one)?

Comment: @LarsSorjetasek I think you might arrive at a better solution (and maybe understand why the "don't use classes here" idea might be a good one) if you try to think about what your class represents.  Start with the name- ask yourself things like, what is a statistic? what information does a statistic contain? what operations can I perform on a statistic?  I think you'll find that intuitively, the "objects" in your program are actually sample arrays, and these are already pretty well modeled by vectors.

Comment: @LarsSorjetasek There's no reason to write it more than once though. Chuck those related functions in their own file (utils or whatever), give them a namespace and include them where you need them! IMHO you should sometimes ask whether there's a good reason _to_ use classes :-) Back on the initial question, if you're insisting on using the classes, and one of the vectors you're using belongs to the class you're calling the method from, then you only need the prototype `double calcCovariance(vector<double> &otherSample)`.

Comment: @splrs: thanks, and you're def right about the last one ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the function outside of the class (which I don't think is required following the discussion :-) ) and if the `Statistics` class is for some reason required, provide an accessor to `sample` e.g.

```
namespace utilitystuff
{
    double calcCovariance(const vector<double> &s1, const vector<double> &s2)
    {
        //definition
    }
}
```

Accessor to sample:

```
const vector<double>& Statistics::getSample{return sample;}
```

And call it like so:

```
//Assuming we have Statistics objects stats1 and stats2.
double covariance = utilitystuff::calcCovariance(stats1.getSample(), stats2.getSample());
```

Answer (score 0):

define you class something like this:

```
class Statistic{
public:
    // constructors
    Statistic();
    explicit Statistic(vector<double> &s);

    // other functions
    double calcMean(void) const;
    double calcVariance(void) const;

    double calcCovariance(const Statistic &other) const;

private:
    vector<double> sample;
};
```

and implement something like:

```
double Statistic::calcCovariance(const Statistic &other) const
{
// TODO: use other.sample and sample here.
}
```